# npm install -g ember-cli error MSB3191

Tags: ember-cli

I am on Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2015.

Installing **Ember-cli** getting following error. has anyone experience it?

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\testem\
node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  
else (node  rebuild )
```

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targe
ts(312,5): error MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "Release\obj\bufferutil
\bufferutil.tlog\bufferutil.lastbuildstate". The specified path, file name, or
both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characte
rs, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters. [C:\Users\[username]\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\testem\node_modules\soc
ket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules
\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
```